# Samsung phone will not charge from laptop's USB-C port

Tags: laptop, dell-latitude, usb-c, charging

I am using a [Dell Latitude 5400](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/latitude-14-5400-laptop/latitude_5400_servicemanual/dell-latitude-5400-service-manual?guid=guid-5b8de7b7-879f-45a4-88e0-732155904029&lang=en-us) (running Windows 10 Pro OS) which is equipped with a USB-C port. Typically I use this port to connect the docking station. However, when I am mobile I am finding my myself in need charging from the USB-C to a cell phone, a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 5G to be precise (as many phones now comes with USB-C to USB-C charging cables instead of USB-A to USB-C). The USB-A ports work fine charging devices, just not the USB-C.

Is there a setting (or similar) on the laptop to know if my USB-C port can provide power to devices instead on just receiving it from the docking station?

*Note I am asking about the computer interface rather than the phone as the phone charges perfectly fine under all other circumstances.

Comment: Most likely yes, though I wouldn't be surprised if in some odd cases the phone might charge your laptop back. Also don't expect it to charge very quickly anyway.

Comment: You need to edit your question to add specifics on the types of devices you are attempting to charge. It entirely depends on the device and what kind of USB-C charging itself is supported. USB A is a 100% dumb protocol. Some devices are USB-C PD (Power Delivery) while others are QC (Quick Charge). But wait! There’s more! The [Wikipedia page for USB-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C) explains nothing is simple with USB-C. In general, a USB A to USB-C cable will be useful for all devices; USB-C to USB-C cables only on specific device combos.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 details added. it is a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 5G.

Comment: When you plug in your phone do you get the USB connection notification? If so try to change the USB connection mode to "charge this device"